# How to modify list elements while iterating over the list?

Tags: python, list, iterable

In Python it is not possible to modify a list while iterating over it. For example, below I cannot modify `list_1` and the result of the `print` will be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. In the second case, I loop over a list of class instances, and calling the `set_n` method modifies the instances in the list, while iterating over it. Indeed, the `print` will give `[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]`.

How are these two cases different, and why?

```
# First case: modify list of integers 
list_1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for l in list_1:
    l += 1
print(list_1)

# Second case: modify list of class instances
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        
    def set_n(self, n):
        self.n = n
        
list_2 = [Foo(3)] * 5
for l in list_2:
    l.set_n(4)
print([l.n for l in list_2])
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other questions; the question isn't about whether it's safe to modify the elements, and it isn't about why it isn't safe to add or remove elements. The question is **why assigning to the iteration variable doesn't** modify the corresponding element in the underlying list. We need a proper canonical for that. Leaving this closed for now, but.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It certainly is possible to modify a list while iterating over it, you just have to reference the list, not a variable that contains the list value.

```
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    list_1[i] += 1
```

The difference in the second case is that the variable contains a reference to a mutable container object. You're modifying the contents of that object, not assigning to the variable.